# How to display string variables as bold text with gnuplot for Windows

Tags: gnuplot

To display a title in **bold** face is simple: just `set title "{/:Bold <title>}"`

When the title is not plain text, but a string variable... that does not work.

I've searched "face" and "set term" in the manual for getting some hint, but what they call 'face' therein, seems to be what is commonly called "font" (Arial, for example). Besides, does there exist one command so as to make all text bold (title, tics and labels)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are at least two ways:

```
reset session
myTitle = "This is my title in bold"
set title sprintf("{/:Bold %s}",myTitle)
plot x
```

or explicitely setting the bold version of the font if it is available

```
reset session
myTitle = "This is my title in bold"
set title myTitle font "Arial Bold,10"
plot x
```

Comment: @theozhThe 1st way is a good one since my title is a chain made of plain text + a couple of string variables joined by the usual dot. The 2nd way works only for a limited number of fonts (Times-New Roman is not one of them, for example). For tics, `set xtics format sprintf("{/:Bold %<MyFormat>}")  <start>, <incr> {,<end>}`  works fine, but when I use `set xtics add <list>` it just ignores the format (no error messages either), no matter whether it is placed before or after the tics list.

Comment: @ifffam interesting with the manually added tics. Looks like an unintended behaviour, i.e. a bug. By the way, e.g. `set term wxt font "Arial Bold,"` will set everything (titles, labels, tics, ...) to bold in one "shot"... then apparently even the manually added xtics.

Comment: `@theozh`it may not be a bug, but just a format issue... those tics that I've added manually are timestamp-like of the kind "01 apr", "11 apr", "21 apr", "01 may", "11 may" etc. Timedate data are always a bit tricky... the `set xtics format` in my previous comment works well for %s format but it gives the n° of seconds since 1 Jan 1970. So now I have to try something *of the kind* `set xtics format strftime("{/:Bold %d %b}",sprintf("{/:Bold %s}"))` This, obviously, doesn't work (nor removing the last /:Bold))  [`set xtics add` will use this very format automatically without re-typing it]